# Is this an object?

Tags: javascript

Is this an object: `[ [ 5, 'yes' ], [ 8, 'no' ] ]` ?

There is a code that looks like this

`myFunction( [ [ 5,'yes' ], [ 8 , 'no'] ] );`

but I want to append values to the data inside the function param programmatically.

In other words, I want to call something like this instead:

```
 var d = new Object();
 var d = addValue(5,'yes');
 var d = addValue(8,'no');
 ....
 myFunction(d);
```

Is this right? Would I use an object here?
If so, how do I append individual values to the object?

Comment: You're passing in an array, so just construct one: `var array = []; array.push([2, 'foo']);`

Comment: Arrays are also objects so technically it *is* an object, but not the kind of object you'd construct with `new Object()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an object: `[ [ 5, 'yes' ], [ 8, 'no' ] ]` ?

It is an array literal, which is an expression to evaluates to an array. Every array is an object, yes, but you want an Array specifically.

> I want to append values to the data inside the function param programmatically.

Then start with an empty array, and [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the subarrays to it.

```
var d = [];
d.push( [5,'yes'] );
d.push( [8,'no'] );
…
myFunction(d);
```